# How do you evaluate variable as option name in R?

Tags: r, eval

I have two variables, as follows:

```
tokenName = "myToken"
tokenResult = "myResult"
```

I'd like to set `options()` where I evaluate the variable `tokenName` and set that option as `myResult`.

Essentially I want the equivalent of `options(myToken = tokenResult)`, but using the variable `tokenName`.

I tried `options(eval(tokenName) = tokenResult)` but to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
do.call(options, as.list(setNames(tokenResult, tokenName)))
```

-checking

```
options()[[tokenName]]
#[1] "myResult"
```

Comment: do we really need the `do.call`?  From help, "options can also be passed by giving a single unnamed argument which is a named list."  So `options(as.list(setNames(tokenResult, tokenName)))` also seems to work

Comment: @dww that would also work.  I used `do.call` as it is a bit more general

Comment: This worked amazing for one of my options. However, another option I want to try is with an environment instead of a string. For example, instead of ```tokenResult = "myResult"```,  tokenResult would be an Environment. When I try the same principle it throws an error saying ```cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'```.

Comment: I've generated a Google Token through oauth, and it saved an ```R6 object of classes Token2.0, Token```. I'd like to create an option where the user can give the name of the option stored as a string and the option would contain this R6 object.

Comment: @Jacob can you please post as a new question  with more details as you are generating R6 object and this may involve different methods for extraction and assignment

Comment: Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756783/how-do-you-add-an-environment-option-with-an-evaluated-name-in-r