# How do you add an environment option with an evaluated name in R?

Tags: r, eval

I created a google token (R6 object of classes Token2.0, Token) to so I can interact with the YouTube Analytics API as follows:

```
google_token <- httr::oauth2.0_token(httr::oauth_endpoints("google"),
                                     httr::oauth_app("google", appId, appSecret),
                                     scope = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"))
```

I also have a variable `Account <- "myChannel"`. Similar to a previous question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756556/how-do-you-evaluate-variable-as-option-name-in-r/67756560?noredirect=1#comment119763262_67756560) I would like to evaluate `Account` and assign the value to be the content of `google_token`. For example, `options(myChannel, google_token)` works, and running `getOption("myChannel")` shows the token, but because I will generate various tokens and want to create various options, I want to use `Account`. I would hope something like the following works:

```
options(eval(Account) = google_token

# OR

do.call(options, as.list(setNames(google_token, Account)
```

Neither of which work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the second options, is there a typo i.e. `do.call` instead of `docall`.  Also, have you tried `options(as.list(setNames(google_token, Account)))`

Comment: Ah yes, typo on the do.call when writing the question. No, unfortunatly the ```options(as.list(setNames(google_token, Account)))``` didnt work either

Comment: does it have setOptions method

Comment: Within ```oauth2.0_token()```? Not that I see

Comment: r6 have get set methods  ie why you getOption return value

Comment: Oh, within the google_token? I don't see any option related values in it

Comment: Sorry, I tried to set up the apiID for ytanalytics, but it seems to be having some trouble

Comment: Were you ever able to get the api working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by assigning the option value to a list, naming the list whatever I wanted it to be in the option, and then assigning the option, as follows:

```
tokenOption <- list(google_token)
names(tokenOption) <- Account
options(tokenOption)

getOption("myChannel")
> #Gives me the results of my google_token
```